# openldap: grant global read access to a user

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

System: Ubuntu 10.10
OpenLDAP 2.4.23

I have a user that I want to give global read rights to.  I used webmin to do so, but somehow that app corrupts the olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif file, so I am looking for another way to do this.

Before this, I was used to a different verison of ldap and am a bit lost with where I need to make the change.

Can anyone give me a pointer?

```
:/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config# ls -la
total 32
drwxr-x--- 3 openldap openldap 4096 2011-01-31 18:28 .
drwxr-x--- 3 openldap openldap 4096 2011-01-31 18:26 ..
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap  457 2011-01-20 01:24 cn=module{0}.ldif
drwxr-x--- 2 openldap openldap 4096 2011-01-31 18:26 cn=schema
-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  307 2011-01-20 01:09 cn=schema.ldif
-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  440 2011-01-22 20:24 olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
-rw-r----- 1 openldap openldap  583 2011-01-22 20:23 olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif
-rw------- 1 openldap openldap 1149 2011-01-31 18:26 olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cn=config, then you shouldn't be editing files to change the configuration. Try reading some documentation, for example [LDAP for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html).

Comment: That links talks about using a specific tool - I am wondering if there's a link to where I can learn how to manage this via the command line.

Comment: `ldapadd` and `ldapmodify` ? I like to use `ldapvi`